# MYSQL/PHP update field on login

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a login page and in the db table i have a field called last_access to store last login date and time the data type is timestamp

The following is the select statement;

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE $db_usercol='$myusername' and $db_passcol='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

How can i update the field "last_access" every time the user logs in? and set the value to NOW().

Thanks

Comment: What would happen if I tried logging in with the password `' OR '' = '`?

Comment: The update statement should be after the user has been authenticated right

Comment: If you want to update it when the user logs in, then it should be done after the user logs in.  That means after authentication :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE $tbl_name set last_access = NOW() WHERE $db_usercol='$myusername'
```

or you could use

```
UPDATE $tbl_name set last_access = NOW() WHERE 
               $db_usercol='$myusername' AND $db_passcol='$mypassword'
```

instead of your select, and check how many rows were affected. If none ->login unsuccessfull. if 1 -> login successfull. If more, you got a problem...

But first thing should be removing that SQL injection vulnerability!

Check http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php , some changes would be needed in your SQL functions but it is actually pretty easy to use, example:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdbname", 'dbuser', 'dbpass');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * from table where column = :column');
$stmt->bindParam(':column', $column);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

It is easy and SQL injection attacks will be unsuccesfull

Comment: +1 I think a simple explanation on how to avoid SQL injections would be useful to Jose! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the login script/function:

```
$sql = sprintf("UPDATE %s SET last_access = NOW() WHERE id = %d", $tbl_name, $user_id);
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just a strange way of creating strings. You can remove it and create your strings using the PHP way: `"UPDATE $table_name SET last_access = NOW() WHERE id = ".(int)$user_id`

Comment: @Basti Why is it a strange way of creating strings? Why not just call it what it is?

Comment: sprintf supports a legion of type specifiers and these are all there to save you from the otherwise impending doom of insecure scripts that are susceptible to the notorious SQL injection attacks. They should really be used on a common basis! Somebody breaching your PHP script's security has to be a rather embarrassing situation to be in.

Comment: @mark_nsx See [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and prepared statements to solve SQL injection issues the right way.

Answer (score 0):

After successful authentication, you could do:

```
//get the id after user has logged in then run the update query
mysql_query("UPDATE your_table SET `last_access` = NOW() WHERE id =".$id);
```